# A funcao nao esta sendo chamada no serviço - Angular

Tags: angular

limite-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { CalculoService } from './calculo.service';
import { Dados } from './dados';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-limite-cliente',
  templateUrl: './limite-cliente.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./limite-cliente.component.css']
})
export class LimiteClienteComponent implements OnInit {

  calculoService: CalculoService;
  private dados: Dados = new Dados();

  constructor(_calculoService: CalculoService) {
    this.calculoService = _calculoService;
  }

  pegadado() {
    console.log(this.dados)
    console.log(this.calculoService)
  }

  ngOnInit() {


  }
}
```

dados.ts

```
export class Dados{
    pago: number;
    emprestimo: number;
    devendo: number;
    Disponivel: number;

}
```

calculo.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import {Dados} from './dados'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CalculoService {

    emprestimo:number;
    pago:number;
    devendo:number;
    Disponivel:number;
    //mostrarGraficoEmitter = new EventEmitter<boolean>(false);

  pegadado(dados:Dados) {

    this.emprestimo = dados.emprestimo;
    this.pago = dados.pago;
    this.devendo = this.emprestimo - this.pago;
    this.Disponivel = 3500 - (this.pago + this.devendo);
    if (this.devendo == 0) {
      this.pago = 0
      this.Disponivel = 3500
    }

    return [this.emprestimo,this.pago,this.Disponivel,this.devendo];        
  }
}
```

limite-cliente.html

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="panel-row">
        <div class="painel-butao">
            <div class="painel-emprestimo">
                <label for="emprestimo">Emprestimo</label>
                <input [(ngModel)]="dados.emprestimo" id="emprestimo" type="number"
                    placeholder="Digite quanto foi emprestado">
                <label for="pago"> pago</label>
                <input [(ngModel)]="dados.pago" id="pago" type="number" placeholder="Digite quanto foi pago">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="action" (click)="pegadado()" >calcular</button>
        </div>
```

A funcao pegadado do servico nao esta sendo chamada e nao estou conseguindo printar no console o valor.

Comment: Não ficou clara sua questão, parece estar tudo certo, talvez vc esteja fazendo confusão na função **pegadado** do arquivo `calculo.service` com a função do arquivo `limite.component`.

Comment: pois e, mas na hora de printar a funcao com o console a funcao do calculo.service nao roda (por exemplo se colocar valores antes da funcao eles sao printados) e no caso era pra rodar as duas funcoes.

Comment: Mas a do service não vai rodar nunca mesmo, vc não está executando ela em nenhum lugar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu problema é que vc está tentando executar a função **pegadado()** que faz os cálculos no arquivo **`calculo.service`** no arquivo **`limite.ts`** sem referenciar a função. Para referenciar a função é simples:

**limite-component.ts**

```
pegadado() {
   console.log(this.dados)

   this.calculoService.pegadado(this.dados)   // referencia a função
}
```

**calculo.service.ts**

```
pegadado(dados: Dados) {
   this.emprestimo = dados.emprestimo;
   this.pago = dados.pago;
   this.devendo = this.emprestimo - this.pago;
   this.Disponivel = 3500 - (this.pago + this.devendo);

   if (this.devendo == 0) {
     this.pago = 0;
     this.Disponivel = 3500;
   }

   // só para ver como já está fazendo os cálculos com os valores de limite.component
   console.log(`Empréstimo ${this.emprestimo} - Pago ${this.pago}
      Disponível ${this.Disponivel} - Devendo ${this.devendo}`)

   return [this.emprestimo, this.pago, this.Disponivel, this.devendo];
}
```

> Pode ver o seu exemplo funcionando [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-calculo-service).

Comment: Sabia q era besteira pq ontem tinha funcionado e hj nao pq fiz algumas dificacoes! obrigado!

Comment: De nada, isso é normal com desenvolvimento.